# Does join parallelise well in Spark?

Tags: apache-spark

I'm running a fairly small Spark program with a few map and reduceByKey operations, over a very small data set of **less than 400MB**.

At some point I have an RDD of tuples that I want to sort, and I call **sortByKey**. This is the slowest part of my program. Everything else seems to run almost instantly, but this takes up to **20 seconds**.

The problem is, it takes 20 seconds in my laptop, as well as in a cluster of AWS m3.large machines. I've tried with 1, 2 and 3 slaves, and the differences in execution time are very small. Ganglia and the spark web console indicate that CPUs and memories are being used to maximum capacity in all slaves, so I think config is ok.

I also found the issue of the execution happening before I expected, but then [I read this thread](http://apache-spark-user-list.1001560.n3.nabble.com/non-lazy-execution-of-sortByKey-td3835.html), which points to an open issue in Spark. I don't think that's entirely related though.

Is it **sortByKey** inherently slow and it doesn't matter how many nodes I add, it's going to dictate the minimum execution time of my program? Hopefully not, and there is just something I'm doing wrong and can be fixed.

**EDIT**

Turns out that what I was seeing was related to that link I posted. sortByKey just happened to be the first action (documented as transformation), and it looked as if the program was being slow at sorting, but actually sorting is quite fast. The problem is in a previous **join** operation.

Still everything I said applies by changing sort with join. Why is the execution time not dropping when I add more nodes (or numTask to the join function), and why is it not even better than a plain SQL join? I found [someone else having this problem](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/spark-users/Ber8KXY2OfU) before, but no answer other than suggesting tuning serialisation, which I really don't think is my case.

Comment: What level of parallelism are you seeing for the slow stage? How many partitions does your RDD have?

Comment: I've played a lot around with a) number of nodes (2 cores per node), b) number of slices for the sc.textFile method, and c) number of tasks for the join method, from the default values to very low values (2) or 3 per node (18), in interval of 2 (so 2, 4, 6, ...). I have seen differences, but not big enough. Also I would expect those to not depend on the number of the nodes, and they do, meaning, setting the numbers to the second parameter of the methods would work better with different number of nodes on the same entry files. That shouldn't be the case I believe.

Comment: Make sure you have 2-4 tasks per CPU otherwise adding nodes won't make a difference - you may need to `.repartition` your data.  Also you have to watch out for network IO when adding nodes.  Usually one very fat node will process data much faster than several small ones, but of course if that node dies, so does your job.

Comment: When you play around with the number of tasks for the join stage, how many do you see running concurrently at once in the Web UI? For example, having 10, 20, or 80 tasks for a stage doesn't mean much if you always see only 2 tasks execute at a time.

Comment: A tip: You can speed up joins quite a bit if you make sure to use the same partitioner on both RDDs.

Comment: Hi Daniel. Would you mind elaborating a bit more or do you have some URL than can help with that? I've looked at the docs and googled around but can't make the connection between explicitly choosing partitioners and the problem I'm seeing. Thanks!

Answer (score 17):

A join is inherently a heavy operation, because values with identical keys must be moved to the same machine (a network shuffle). Adding more nodes is just going to add extra IO overhead.

I can think of 2 things:

**Option 1**

If you are joining a large dataset with a smaller one, it can pay off to broadcast the smaller dataset:

```
val large = sc.textFile("large.txt").map(...) 
val smaller = sc.textFile("smaller.txt").collect().toMap() 
val bc = sc.broadcast(smaller)
```

And then do a 'manual join':

```
large.map(x => (x.value, bc.value(x.value)))
```

This is described in more detail in [this Advanced Spark presentation](http://ampcamp.berkeley.edu/wp-content/uploads/2012/06/matei-zaharia-amp-camp-2012-advanced-spark.pdf).

**Option 2**

You could repartition the small dataset, using the same partitioner as the large one (i.e. make sure that similar keys are on the same machine). So, adjust partitioning of the small set to match partitioning of the large one.

This will trigger a shuffle of the small set only. Once the partitioning is correct, the join should be fairly fast, since it will run locally on each cluster node.

Comment: Thanks for your anwser Eric. I asked about the approach of broadcasting at the spark summit to one of the guys in Databricks, but I'm afraid even my smaller collection (<1GB) is too big to benefit from broadcasting. Do you have experience or insight into the sizes that make sense for this? I will check that link though.

Comment: I have never broadcasted more than max 100MB, so I don't have any advice there. Updated my answer a little though.

Comment: Thanks Eric. Another SO user had recommended playing with partitions in another comment. I can't find good documentation or examples for this, though. Any chance you can point me in the right direction? Thanks again.

Comment: @EricEijkelenboom +1 for the advanced spark programming guide! I broadcasted a 10.2 GB dataset to executors with 60GB of RAM allocated to them and saw amazing (manual) join results.

Comment: I am not sure about Option 2; even though you are using the same partitioner, Spark will assign the partitions to workers randomly, causing the second RDD to be sent all over the cluster for the `join()` operation. [Here is a gist](https://gist.github.com/bekce/e14afdc30814e9d4712d0df6ac967cf0) to demonstrate this behavior.